# Nested query for worlwide selection

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to use a MySQL query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM COUNTRY_TABLE WHERE COUNTRY='INDIA'
```

It gives result for data containing country as INDIA, but when country INDIA does not exist in the table, then it should give result for worldwide or total result in single query.

Comment: @Gone can you give me example

Answer (score 0):

```
Set @param = null;

SELECT * 
FROM   your_table 
WHERE  country = CASE 
                   WHEN @param IS NULL THEN country 
                   ELSE @param 
                 END;
```

See it working at SQL Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/da2d82/2

Another solution :

```
SELECT * 
FROM   your_table 
WHERE  country = COALESCE(@param, country);
```

Comment: above code gives error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Select * from PostView where country=case when @param is null then country Else ' at line 3

Comment: when i give input as India still giving all record :(

Comment: did you try the second solution?

Comment: oh I guess a semicolon is missed after `set @param=null`. check the code now.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS ConditionalSelect;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `ConditionalSelect`()
    BEGIN

    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @varCount FROM Country WHERE `name` = 'India';

    IF @varCount >=1 THEN 
        SELECT * FROM Country WHERE `name` = 'India';
    ELSE
        SELECT * FROM Country;
    END IF;         

    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```